# What can I do if I forgot to cream the butter and sugar in my cookie recipe?

Tags: baking, cookies

I got distracted and forgot to cream the butter and sugar before making sugar cookies.  I baked half and they were dry, tasted like flour and smelled like flour (although rolled in sugar and cinnamon).  I still have half of the batch left in the fridge.  What can I do to make it taste better?  I'm sure it was from not creaming first.

Comment: I don't think lack of creaming would affect the taste -- mostly the texture. Or are you saying you forgot some ingredients? Can you include your recipe so we can see what else is in there that might have affected this?

Answer (score 3):

meh; I have used the “reverse” mixing method for sugar cookies; which is essentially what you did; just need to add more butter and/or cream cheese to pull together now.

The only thing you can't recover from is if you over-mix the flour; if your cookies are glue'y then you over-mixed and you need to throw away.

I find that the details are much more important in sugar cookies; type of flour, type of sugar, butter, ratio; etc...

Letting the dough sit over night will allow autolyseae to happen; as a added bonus.

My recipe:
2 1/2 cups flour; sifted
3/4 cup supppppeeeerrr, superfine sugar (usaully blended in ninja)
1/4 teaspoon salt
16 tablespoons (2 sticks) unsalted butter, cut into 1/2″ pieces & softened
2 tablespoons cream cheese, softened
2 teaspoons vanilla extract

Blend dry ingredients; add butter cubes until desired consistencey; cream cheese to pull dough together.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can do at this point. Discard it and start over, it's just a bit of butter, sugar and flour at the end of the day.

As for it tasting of flour I'm not certain it's your method at fault, I'd say you either forgot the sugar or didn't add enough, or your flour is old. I'd suggest you start again with fresh ingredients.

Comment: I made "sweet" Corn bread without sugar once. Just plum forgot since i was doing it from memory since I make it so often. It was still cornbread but something I would use as a savory garnish or bed for steak. Lol

Comment: I agree about the flour taste not coming from the method, not sure it is necessary to throw everything out, though.

Comment: Sure it is not missing salt?

Comment: If the dough has an incurable textural problem and you're hungry and out of flour...check if it could be upcycled into some kind of cake or quickbread , or diluted into a pourable (pancake/soft tart shell etc.) batter...